# Epsilon Delta proof containing decimal exponents

Tags: epsilon-delta

so I have to prove

lim *x->infinity* ((x^0.8)/(1+x^0.9)) = 0

I am just introduced to epsilon delta, and have no idea how to do this.
Please help :( Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times when trying to prove a limit exists there are distracting terms in the expression which you can safely ignore.
In this case it's the constant one in the denominator.

Explicitly,

$\dfrac{x^{.8}}{1+x^{.9}}
\lt \dfrac{x^{.8}}{x^{.9}}
=\dfrac1{x^{.1}}
$

And now it is easy to choose an $x$
to make this less than
$\epsilon$.

The fact that this is not the best possible value does not matter - you just need to show that the expression gets as small as you want.

This is an example of one of my favorite sayings:

Good enough is good enough.